# Limit of Cosine Integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Prove that $$\lim_{|\xi|\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\cos(\xi x)dx=0$$

Comment: Some hand-waving hint: at any, arbitrarily short interval, you are getting about same number of positive and negative half-sinusoids when $\xi$ grows to infinity.

Comment: First Assume $f \in C_c^\infty$, and use partial integration. For the general case, use the density of $C_c^\infty$ in $L^1$.

Comment: I think I understand. When $f\in C_c^\infty$, integration by parts introduces $\tfrac{1}{\xi}$ terms which limit to $0$. When $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, there exist $g\in C_c^\infty$ arbitrarily close in $L^1$ norm, which means the limit has to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By density of step function in $L^1$, there is $g$ a step function s.t. $\displaystyle\int|f-g|<\varepsilon.$

You have that $$\left|\int f(x)\cos(x\xi)dx\right|\leq \varepsilon+\left|\int g(x) \cos(x\xi)dx\right|$$

To show that $$\lim_{|\xi|\to \infty }\int g(x)\cos(x\xi)dx=0,$$
is easy using the fact that $g$ is a step function. The claim follow.